# Javascript Charset problem

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

I want to read a file from my server with javascript and display it's content in a html page. 
The file is in ANSI charset, and it has romanian characters.. I want to display those characters in the way they are :D not in different black symbols..

So I think my problem is the charset.. I have a get request that takes the content of the file, like this:

```
function IO(U, V) {//LA MOD String Version. A tiny ajax library.  by, DanDavis
var X = !window.XMLHttpRequest ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest();
X.open(V ? 'PUT' : 'GET', U, false );
X.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'Charset=UTF-8');
X.send(V ? V : '');return X.responseText;}
```

As far as I know the romanian characters are included in UTF-8 charset so I set the charset of the request header to utf-8.. the file is in utf-8 format and I have the meta tag that tells the browser that the page has utf-8 content..

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

So if I query the server the direct file, the browser shows me the romanian characters but if I display the content of the page through this script, I see only symbols instead of characters..
So what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

PS: I want this to work on Firefox at least not necessarily in all browsers..

Comment: Content Type needs to be: **text/html; charset=UTF-8**

Comment: What `Content-Type` header do you use with that file?

Comment: well in the text editor is ansi :D if that is the question :D, is not a html page it has just text :D

Comment: I tried "text/html; charset=UTF-8" but it's the same :D

Comment: @Cata: It is irrelevant what your text editor does. The *only* relevant thing is what Content-Type header the web server returns for that particular file.

Comment: @Tomalak: it seems to be ISO-8859-1 the charset :D, i took it from firefox :)

Comment: @Cata: Can you confirm that this is that the charset declaration that you also see if you load the file *on its own*?

Comment: @Cata let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1456/discussion-between-tomalak-and-cata)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While my initial assumption was the same as T.J. Crowder's, a [quick chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/1456) established that the OP uses some hosting service and cannot easily change the Content-Type headers.

The files were sent as `text/plain` or `text/html` without any `Charset` paramter, hence the browser interprets them as UTF-8 (which is the default).

So *saving* the files in UTF-8 (instead of ANSI/Windows-1252) did the trick.

Comment: I have been doing a prototype with just html pages and I was creating pages on the fly with just right click on a folder (windows) and new file... and all were save with ANSI (without know), before this answer I was becoming crazy to find out why the f"#$%ck the UTF-8 meta was not working... Now I can code again in peace :o)

Answer (score 4):

You need to ensure that the HTTP response returning the file data has the correct charset identified on it. You have to do that server-side, I don't think you can force it from the client. (When you set the content type in the request header, you're setting the content type *of the request*, not the response.) So for instance, the *response* header from the server would be along the lines of:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=windows-1252
```

...if by "ANSI" you mean the [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) charset. That should tell the browser what it needs to do to decode the response text correctly before handing it to the JavaScript layer.

One problem, though: As far as I can tell, Windows-1252 doesn't have the full [Romanian alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_alphabet). So if you're seeing characters like `Ș`, `ș`, `Ţ`, `ţ`, etc., that suggests the source text is not in Windows-1252. Now, perhaps it's okay to drop the diacriticals on those in Romanian (I wouldn't know) and so if your source text just uses `S` and `T` instead of `Ș` and `Ţ`, etc., it could still be in Windows-1252. Or it may be ISO-8859 or ISO-8859-2 (both of which drop some diacriticals) or possibly ISO-8859-16 (which has full Romanian support). [Details here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_alphabet#ISO_8859)

So the first thing to do is determine what character set the source text is actually in.

Comment: I just read that HTML5 standardized that *"ISO-8859-1"* charset declarations must be interpreted as *"Windows-1252"*. Finally.

Comment: Now the page returns the content charset : ISO-8859-1 like the content of the page but the problem is still the same..

Comment: @Cata: The response with the file data has that content type? And you're certain that's the charset of the source text (not, say, ISO-8859-2 or -16)? If the answer is yes to both questions, I'm afraid I don't know what it is.

Comment: it seems that the file with the content send the content charset as simple text.. I have changed the charset of the file to utf and now everything is fine, thanks to Tomalak :D